# Adding button to snackbar Android

Tags: java, android

I'm using [SnackBar](https://github.com/MrEngineer13/SnackBar).

Does anyone know how to add a button like this, and keep it showing?

[image: Snackbar]

Comment: Which button are you talking about?

Comment: It doesn't looks like a Snackbar to me! Rather a layout with textview and button!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [library](https://github.com/MrEngineer13/SnackBar) is designed to show snackbar with a certain style. If you use it as-is you have very limited influence on it's appearance outside the predefined styles.
So you can get access to snack's views after it's creation:

```
mSnackBar = new SnackBar.Builder(this)
    .withOnClickListener(this)
    .withMessage("Text")
    .withActionMessage("Action")
    .withStyle(SnackBar.Style.DEFAULT)
    .show();

TextView snackButton = (TextView) mSnackBar.getContainerView().
                        findViewById(R.id.snackButton); \\ now you can modify the style of action view
```

But keep in mind that in this way you are modifying View that already exists and is already visible to user. So here may be some visual artifacts when changing the style (blinking for example).

To avoid undesirable effects you have 2 options:

- look out for another lib;
- as this library is open-source you can download sources, modify SnackBar.Button style as you need, and connect to your project as a module.